# Read data row wise from a file(.txt or .dat) in matlab

Tags: matlab, fopen, textscan

I want to read a row with numeric data from a file which contains one text line and few lines with numeric data.
I have tried this by using fopen and textscan(as all string value) command in MATLAB. After loading all the data and trying to do any mathematical operation it is showing the following error.

Undefined function or method 'plus' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

I'm trying to loading the following file which contains following data:

K    V    M     UV    JV    CI     SI    JRM    MRJ     MIM   JIJ     VB       UB
  90000       0       0       0       0       0       0       0   10800  216000  205200  226800  205200  431940  215970  215970

165026     122     122      99      23     105       7      27   10811  215874  275166  226800  205200  431940  215970  215970

165027     132     122      49      23     115       9      97   10911  215674  275166  226800  205200  431940  215970  215970

165028     142     122      79      23     155       7      107   10711  215774  225166  226800  205200  431940  215970  215970

I require only the numerical data of 3rd row for my use.Please help me.

Thank you for your help in this regards.
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple things going on here, and without seeing your code, it's hard to know exactly what the problem is.

When you load the data in as a string, it's exactly that, a string, so operators like `plus` aren't going to get you very far. `textscan` also returns a cell array, which is fine for holding different types of data in a single variable, but not so great for doing math on.

As long as your file isn't ridiculously long, and you know the format, you could parse the file line-by-line with `fgetl`.

```
m = 1;
fid = fopen(fileName);
headerLine = fgetl(fid);% read in the first line, then ignore it
dataLine = fgetl(fid); 
while ischar(fileLine) % EOF will return -1
    C = textscan(dataLine,'%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f','delimiter',char(32));
    firstVariable(m) = C{1};
    secondVariable(m) = C{2}; % etc.
    blankLine = fgetl(fid); %this line is blank
    dataLine = fgetl(fid); %this line has data, read it in and finish the loop 
    m = m +1;
end 
fclose(fid)
```

If you know (or can otherwise calculate) the number of lines you will have beforehand, you can and should preallocate your variables, or things will slow way down. If you have a good idea on an upper limit, you can allocate more space than you'll need and then trim them down at the end using the value of `m`.